# Running bash script inside VS Code with Cmder terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I've just installed VS Code and added Cmder as a default terminal on a new Win10.

I am trying to import my git for Windows `.bashrc` aliases to be used with Cmder. So I've added them to `user_aliases.cmd`.

Example alias:

```
make=./bin/webpack-make.sh
```

If I run Cmder separately, aliases scripts run OK.  When I run them trough the VS Code terminal, I get this message:

> λ dev
>   '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I add the full path I get:

> λ dev
>   The system cannot execute the specified program.`

**Any Ideas why is this happening?**

btw, I've added Cmder and VSCode with Scoop.

Answer (score 0):

Cmder (actually the ConEmu) is a terminal. But you are trying to configure aliases for use by shell (cmd.exe I believe). The difference is described [here](https://conemu.github.io/en/TerminalVsShell.html).

You have two options:

- Run bash in Cmder (ConEmu) and use aliases as usual in bash. To do that just choose appropriate startup shell [Settings/Startup](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsStartup.html)
- Modify the alias to run sh-script via bash. Sort of `make=sh.exe -c ./bin/webpack-make.sh`

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving some tips. I have tried those and they don't fix the issue for now. Will try stuff and get beck  if anything works.

The thing is If I run Cmnder naively  a with {bash::bash} all is OK, all aliases work fine. If I run in in VSCode, git aliases work fine but not the .sh scrips.

Comment: Look at [StatusBar](https://conemu.github.io/en/StatusBar.html). It shows what shell you actually started. I believe it's not bash.